# Version Number Plugin Causes Pipeline Parsing Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The documentation says that the Version Number Plugin works with pipelines, and it is included in the Pipeline Snippet Generator.

The Snippet Generator gave me this as a simple example:

```
VersionNumber projectStartDate: '', versionNumberString: 'bob', versionPrefix: ''
```

I put this line into my Pipeline script, and it chokes when trying to parse it:

```
WorkflowScript: 92: unexpected token: projectStartDate @ line 92, column 22.
          VersionNumber projectStartDate: '', versionNumberString: 'bob', versionPrefix: ''
                        ^
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. I fixed it with something like

```
VersionNumber(versionNumberString : '1.0-${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}', projectStartDate : '2017-03-16')
```

Answer (score 1):

VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '1.0.1_${BUILDS_ALL_TIME, XXX}', projectStartDate: '2017-04-03', versionPrefix: '', worstResultForIncrement: 'SUCCESS')

it also worked for me.